# Unmanaged Exceptions

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-4.0

I have a method that calls an unmanaged library from a background thread.  I put a try catch block around the unmanaged call but it is never caught.  The just in time debugger catches it instead.  What am I doing wrong?

```
    public bool TurnOn()
    {
        var connectionSucceeded = false;
        try
        {
            connectionSucceeded = turnOn(); //Unmanaged call
        }
        catch
        {
            connectionSucceeded = false; //Never reaches this block                
        }

        return connectionSucceeded;
    }
```

Comment: you use .net 4.0? In .net 4.0 this problem may be, when in 3.5 not.

Comment: Document what you see in the Output window.

Answer (score 1):

Is the debugger setup to handle unmanaged exceptions when they are thrown?

Check the setting in Debug>Exceptions

Also, is the unmanaged exception definitely thrown on the thread directly being called - and not in some async operation on a different thread?

Comment: Either way it should either show up in the catch block or the UnhandledException event.  It does not do either.

Comment: If it's thrown on a new thread - one created by the native code - then I don't think it will show up in your handler.

Comment: How would I catch something like that?

Comment: AFAIK, I'm not sure you can - if it's a native exception on a thread without any native try/catch handling, then I think that's game over. But first of all, is there any way you can check that this is actually the problem - e.g. what does the native stack trace show you? What is the native "turnon"? Is it something you have the pdb/dbg symbols or the source code for?

Comment: I do not have any pdb/dbg symbols or any access to the source.

Comment: does the turnon method throw an exception if called from native code? - e.g. from a native C++ app?

Answer (score 1):

I fully agree with **Stuart** answer.. In this case you could try catch exception on application level:

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += UnhandledExceptionEventRaised;
```

Plz see also this answer: [AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException not firing without debugging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1300319/appdomain-currentdomain-unhandledexception-not-firing-without-debugging/1300493#1300493)

Comment: Sorry let me be more clear.  That event does fire, just not in the case of unmanaged exceptions.

Comment: Plz look to referenced answer and try it.

Comment: The referenced answer uses winforms methods as part of the solution, I'm using wpf